# UIPageViewController inside a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

I'm playin around with UIPageViewController and using a UIPageViewController as a standalone controller everything i need works like a charm.
I'm now in the needed to add some controllers to the PageController, and i've implemented a UIViewController and added everything to this ViewController.
Everything works perferctly except that UIPageViewController is not notified for device rotation, as it's not the firstResponder.
How can i solve it ? i've tried to call spinelocationForInterfaceOrientation manually in viewWillRotateToInterfaceRotation but it's not like i would... does anyone have any hint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is your UIViewController a delegate of UIPageViewController?

If not, try this:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
```

and implement this:

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```